# $H$-orbits in X have not the same cardinality if $H$ is not normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, galois-theory

Let $G$ be a transitive subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ on $n$ letters,
and let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. I know that the action of $G$ on the set
$X =\{ 1,..., n \}$ induces a natural action of $G$ on the set $X_H  = \{ H_x; x \in X \}$ of subsets of $X$ consisting of the orbits for $H$ in $X$.

I also showed that all the $H$-orbits in $X$ have the same cardinality. However I want to find an example to illustrate the failure of this conclusion when $H$ is not assumed to be normal in $G$. What this example should be?

Thanks

Comment: A quick note on notation: $H_x$ usually denotes the subgroup of $H$ whose elements fix $x$.  If you want the orbits of $H$, the notations $Hx$ and $H \cdot x$ are both common.

Answer (score 0):

Just take $H$ to be the subgroup generated by one transposition, say $(12)$. Then what do the orbits look like?

Most of the elements are fixed, so you have a bunch of singleton orbits like $\{5\}$, but not for $1$ and $2$, right..?